# How to do 2 different redirect using a tag?

Tags: html, redirect, anchor

I'm already using jQuery UI tabs, so I have **`li`** framed the html like

```
<li>
  <a href='#expenses_menu'>Expenses</a>
</li>
```

Here I'm already using **`href`** to redirect an id since jQuery UI tabs .  Along with this I need to redirect to **`/Home.aspx`**

Is there any workaround to perform this 2 href using `a` tag?

Comment: can you please elaborate. You want to switch tabs and redirect at the same time? what do you want to redirect? You want to load a file into the tab?

Comment: @mplungjan absolutely (`You want to switch tabs and redirect at the same time`).  I am trying to redirect to home page.

Comment: That doesn't really clarify the issue. If you switch the tab and redirect at the same time, switching the tab has no effect because you immediately move to another page.

Comment: What is the point of switching tabs AND redirecting?  They would click the link and the tab would change but that wouldn't matter because they'd already be redirected to another page.

Comment: However this would be very simple to do with javascript, just bind a click event handler to `#expenses_menu` that changes `window.location.href` to your redirect url.